# appendChild not working in for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to append an existing div (var parent) to a new div multiple times in the code. Here is my code. It appends the existing div to the last created div. help me out.

```
var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var rowCount = result.length;
var parent = document.getElementById("post-feed");
for(i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.id = "post-id-"+result[i].postid;
    newdiv.className = "row";
    newdiv.appendChild(parent);
    document.getElementById("feed").appendChild(newdiv);
    document.getElementById("post-msg").innerHTML = result[i].message;
    var image = result[i].image;
    if(image != null){
        document.getElementById("image").src = "uploads/"+image;
    }
```

Comment: Well of course. You're iteratively moving `parent` around until, as the loop ends, it ends in its resting place, the final element it was appended to. Sounds like you're trying to clone, since your current aim makes little sense otherwise.

Comment: wait, you want to append the parent to these new elements? If yes, that is not possible to have one element in multiple locations so you would need to clone it.  If the new elements are supposed to be in the parent element than you have your logic switched.

Comment: cloning isn't helping much since It doesn't clone child divs of parent div.

Comment: I have tried cloning but it is not giving desired result.

Comment: Unclear what you mean.... What are you trying to do exactly? Where are the new elements supposed to live? What is supposed to be inside the new elements?

Comment: I want the new div to act as parent of the parent div.

Comment: but that parent div can not live in multiple places. That is your issue.

Comment: yes that's the problem. @epascarello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One element can not live in multiple places so if you want to reuse the markup of an element, than you can use cloneNode to clone it.

```
document.getElementById("feed").appendChild(newdiv.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: will the child divs of the parent get automatically cloned by that? I have tried cloning but it isn't cloning the child divs.

Comment: cloning is working fine. I was using cloneNode() earlier which was creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have flip flopped your child and parent on line 8 there. I think you want to say parent.appendChild(newDiv);

Comment: I want the new div to act as parent of the parent div

Comment: Here is a thought. If you have already appended the parent div to a new div, you may run into errors on the next run of the loop as the parent div is already the child of another div.

Comment: I'm calling the parent by its id which is unique. so it will not create any problem as such.